# Always redirected to current route instead of desired route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

I am using ternary operator to render component using react route. But I am always redirected to "/" route instead of desired component even if the condition is as expected.

I get desired functionality only when I refresh/reload the page.

This is my App.js with all the routes

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Header from './Components/Header';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Checkout  from "./Components/Checkout";
import Payment from "./Components/Payment";
import NewProduct from "./Components/NewProduct";
import OrderSuccess from "./Components/OrderSuccess";
import AddressForm from './Components/AddressForm';
import {BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Login from './Components/Login';
import Orders from "./Components/Orders";
import Account from './Components/Account';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const App=()=>{

  const user = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")));

  const defaultRoutes= ()=>{
    return(
      <div>
    <Header/>
    <Switch>
    <Route  path="/account-settings" exact component={()=>user ? <Account />: <Redirect to="/" />} />
    <Route  path="/orders" exact component={()=>user ? <Orders /> : <Redirect to="/" />} />
    <Route  path="/checkout" exact component={()=>user ? <Checkout />: <Redirect to="/" />} />
    <Route  path="/payment" exact component={()=>user ? <Payment /> : <Redirect to="/" />} />
    <Route  path="/account-settings/add-new-address" exact component={()=>user?.result ? <AddressForm /> : <Redirect to="/" />} />
    <Route  path="/" exact component={Home} />
    </Switch>
    </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <Route  path="/login" exact component={()=>user ? <Redirect to="/" />:<Login />} />
    <Route component={defaultRoutes} />
    </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import "./index.css"
import reducers from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(reducers,{},compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById("root")
)
```

This is reducer where I am updating my localstorage

```
export default (state={authData:null},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "AUTH":
            localStorage.setItem("profile",JSON.stringify({...action?.data}));
            return {...state, authData: action.data, loading: false, errors: null};
        
        case "LOGOUT":
        localStorage.clear();
        return {...state,authData:null};   
        
        default:
            return "";    
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anything trigger `App` to rerender so it *possibly* picks up any changes from localStorage (*other than reloading the app*)?

Comment: I tried that usin useState and useEffect to rerender when state of user changes in localstorage but it didn't worked

Comment: localStorage isn't active, it doesn't notify anything when it updates. Are you updating the localStorage somewhere? Is there something in redux that is also updated? We may need to see the redux code and the component code that is updating any authentication "state".

Comment: It is updated in a reducer file when user sign in and sign out

Comment: Can you please update your question to include all the relevant code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sir you are right App must re render on change of localstorage. I tried using window.addEventListenet but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are close. The issue here is that even though you store the auth in localStorage ***and*** update the redux state, `App` isn't being rerendered to "pick up" the new `auth` value from localStorage.

## Solution

1. Initialize the redux state from localStorage.
2. Select the authentication state from your Redux store. This is so changes to the store trigger subscribed components to rerender.

Auth Reducer

```
const initialState={
  authData:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")),
  loading:false,
  errors:null
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case "AUTH":
      localStorage.setItem("profile", JSON.stringify({ ...action?.data }));
      return {
        ...state,
        authData: action?.data,
        loading: false,
        errors: null
      };

    case "LOGOUT":
      localStorage.clear();
      return { ...state, authData: null };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

App

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const App = () => {

  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.authData);

  const defaultRoutes = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            path="/account-settings"
            render={() => user ? <Account />: <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/orders"
            render={() => user ? <Orders /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/checkout"
            render={() => user ? <Checkout />: <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/payment"
            render={() => user ? <Payment /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/account-settings/add-new-address"
            render={() => user?.result ? <AddressForm /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      ...
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

### Suggestion

Review the [auth workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) and create a `PrivateRoute` component that handles the redirect for you.

Example:

```
const PrivateRoute = props => {
  const user = useSelector(state => state.auth.authData);

  return user ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
};
```

Usage:

```
const App = () => {

  const defaultRoutes = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute path="/account-settings" component={Account} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/orders" component={Orders} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/checkout" component={Checkout} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/payment" component={Payment} />
          <Route
            path="/account-settings/add-new-address"
            render={() => user?.result ? <AddressForm /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
          />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  };

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      ...
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is rendered twice automatically. In console, first time the value of user is available but second time it is undefined.

Comment: What rendered twice automatically? Can you create a *running* codesandbox of your code for us to inspect and debug live? If you're hosted in github you can direct import into codesandbox.

Comment: Sir, is there any other way I can share code or which part do you think is affected and I shoud focus on

Comment: @NamanKedia Do you have your code hosted in github?

Comment: I have deployed project on Heroku but not published on Github. I am trying to make a clone of Amazon though it is just a basic one.

Comment: @NamanKedia Ok, I was just thinking of an easy way to get other eyes on your code or to help create a *running* sandbox. I think we need to see this code running in a development environment so we can set breakpoints and debug it. If I have time I can create one with the limited scope of code you've shared. In the meantime, can you expand upon your first comment that something is rendering twice and console logging odd things? Depending on where you are logging you could be outside the component lifecycle, so any results shouldn't be taken too seriously.

Comment: I changed code according to the answer you gave then in App.js I wrote console.log(user), it got rendered 2 times since i got 2 values in the console first with result and token and second was undefined. Since second was undefined all the routes are considering user to b null and just redirect me back on home page.  This remains same whether I refresh or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238106/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-naman-kedia).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ternary in the router. Use `useHistory` to redirect to `"/"` if the condition is not met.
For checking the condition, create a custom hook called `useCheckUser` which checks if there is a user in the `localStorage`.

In every component where `user` is required,

```js
import useCheckUser from "file-address"
import { useHistory } from "react-router"


const Component = () => {
  let history = useHistory();
  let user = useCheckUser();
  if (!user) {
    history.push("/");
  }

  return ()

}
```

The `useCheckUser` hook should be something similar to

```js
const useCheckUser = () => {
  let user = localStorage.getItem("profile");
  if (user) {
    return JSON.parse(user);
  }
  return null;
};

export default useCheckUser;
```

**NOTE:** If your only requirement is rendering components when the user is present, you can change your custom hook so that it does everything including the redirecting. This is just to return the current `user`. So this can be used if you want to render certain components like auth pages if and only if the `user` is not present.

Comment: can you explain why ternary operator can't be used ?

Comment: I'm sure Ternary can be used in some way. But this is a better method in my opinion. This is going to work in every case and it is more scalable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

try to take the user a State (useState), and set it in the useEffect like this:

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   setUser(localStorage.getItem("profile"))
  }, [])
```

it will set the "user" as your page rendered

Comment: It is not working

Comment: then you should use Protected Routes

Comment: by using protected/ secured routes it will redirect you to the home page if user is not logged in. I can provide you the code if you want.

Comment: yes please help, i haven't used protected routes before

Comment: sure, I'm uploading it in Answer

Comment: and from where do you set the localStorage

Answer (score 0):

```
 function App() {
      const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   setUser(localStorage.getItem("profile"))
  }, [])
    
    const authentication = {
        getLogInStatus() {
          return user;
        },
      };
    }
    
      function SecuredRoute(props) {
        return (
          <Route
            path={props.path}
            render={(data) =>
              authentication.getLogInStatus() ? (
                <props.component
                  {...data}
                ></props.component>
              ) : (
                handleRedirect()
              )
            }
          ></Route>
        );
      }
    
      const handleRedirect = () => {
        let login = window.confirm(
          "please Register or log in to access this page!"
        );
        if (login) {
          return <Redirect path="/"></Redirect>;
        }
      };
    
     return (
     <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
    // those routes which don't needs authetication
    <Route path="/home" compponent={Home} />
    <Route path="/login" compponent={Login} />
    //and others
    // those routes which needs authetication 
      <SecuredRoute path="/bookings" component={Bookings} />
      <SecuredRoute
                    path="/booking-details"
                    component={BookingDetails}
                  />
                  <SecuredRoute path="/favorites" component={Favorites} />
                  <SecuredRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
     </Switch>
     </BrowserRouter>
    
     );
    }
```

Comment: It is not working

Comment: then it's problem with your localStorage, first consol.log() your localStorage, is there any data in it or not

Comment: Data is there, I am getting it in localstorage and some other components are even able to access its data like Home component.